# ansible-galaxy fails to pull roles in gitlab-ci pipeline

Tags: ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ansible-galaxy

`ansible-lint` step in gitlab-ci pipeline is failing because of authentication error while running the `ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml` that pulls the roles dependency defined in the `requirements.yml` and clone the roles from git.

I tried passing the authentication token via CICD variables but it doesn’t like that.

**requirements.yml**

```
- src: git+https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/../ansible/roles/ansible-role-s3-yumrepo.git
  version: master
  scm: git
```

But it fails with below error

```
Starting galaxy role install process

[WARNING]: - ansible-role-s3-yumrepo was NOT installed successfully: -
command /usr/bin/git clone https://gitlab-ci-
token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/../ansible/roles/ansible-role-s3-yumrepo.git
ansible-role-s3-yumrepo failed in directory /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-526mx2pctt4/tmp2n3_tp7_
(rc=128) - Cloning into 'ansible-role-s3-yumrepo'... remote: HTTP Basic:
Access denied fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab-ci-
token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/../ansible/roles/ansible-role-s3-yumrepo.git/'
```

Anyone faced this issue before or know a better way to handle this (edited)

Comment: The `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` is authorized only for _the current repo_; if you want to be able to access other repos, you'll need to create a [personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#personal-access-tokens) (or a project access token if that is available to you) and grant it `repository_read` scope

Comment: I am using personal access token and facing issue with that only.

Comment: Welp, your posted code snippet has 2 references to `CI_JOB_TOKEN` so if you are doing something underhanded by setting `CI_JOB_TOKEN` to your own P.A.T. you'll need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67333570/edit) and show the way you are actually invoking the job. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that ansible-galaxy does not support environment variable substitution. One possible solution could be manual variable substitution using envsubst:

```
cat requirements.template|envsubst > requirements.yml
```

Depending on the environment setup it may be necessary to delete this file later (after the run), as it will contain all the passwords / tokens as plain text.

Another hint how to debug (confirm) that your user and deploy-token is really working, is to temporarily hardcode deploy-token-user and deploy-token

```
src: 'https://<GITLAB_DEPLOY_USER>:<GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN>@mycompany.com/gitlab/prj/my-ansible-role.git'
```

and test it manually.

Comment: The `envsubst` approach is mentioned in multiple place as a viable method, but recommending in the first place to hardcode the tokens in source code is really bad advice. Probably unintended and only as a sample, but bad in any case.

Comment: I am totally agree, that hardcoding sensitive data could never be the solution. This was mentioned as a sample. I have updated my suggestion how to work around this ansible-galaxy limitation in more proper and secure way.

Answer (score 0):

for gitlab-ci you need to edit the requirements.yml

```
- src: git+https://gitlab-ci-token@gitlab.com/../ansible/roles/ansible-role-s3-yumrepo.git
  version: master
  scm: git
```

need to use in job

```
sed -i "s/token/token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}/g" ./requirements.yml
```

we get

```
- src: git+https://gitlab-ci-token:64_sdr54554s45@gitlab.com/../ansible/roles/ansible-role-s3-yumrepo.git
  version: master
  scm: git
```

this working for ansible-galaxy install in gitlab-ci
just need allow access to this project with a CI_JOB_TOKEN in gitlab